# Is it possible for the expression $n=4xy-(x+y)$ to cover all the positive intergers $n$ verifying $n=1(mod4)$

Tags: real-analysis, modular-arithmetic

Let $x,y$ be two positive integers.

Is it possible for the expression $n=4xy-(x+y)$ to cover all the positive integers $n$ verifying $n=1(\mod 4)$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking "given $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$  can we find $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ such that $n=4xy-(x+y)$"?  If so, then sure.  Just take $x=-n,y=0$.  Don't need the congruence on $n$.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, but not for the zero cases.

Comment: No idea what that means.

Comment: @lulu: It means that I cannot find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Sorry, this is really not clear.  I see that you edited you post to exclude my counterexample, but I still don't see how you get $n=1$ this way.  The least your expression can be is $5$.

Comment: @lulu: How you can prove this.

Comment: The partial $\frac {\partial}{\partial x}(4xy-x-y)=4y-1>0$ since $y≥1$.  Thus your function achieves its minimum when $x=1=y$ for which you get the value $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n=4k+1$. We must prove that the equation $4xy-x-y=4k+1$ has integer answers. $$16xy-4x-4y=16k+4\\16xy-4x-4y+1=16k+5\\(4x-1)(4y-1)=16k+5$$
if $16k+1$ has a prime factor of form $4q-1$ the equation has such answers otherwise not. For example take $k=2$. There are no integer $x,y$ such that $(4x-1)(4y-1)=37$ or equivalently:$$4xy-x-y=9$$